# alias a name for the clause of a macro

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to alias some `racket` `2htdp` functions/macros, so that I can translate them in another language for my children.

Things which are functions I can simply alias with `define`. I'm having trouble with the `big-bang` structure; If I try to alias `on-tick` for instance, everytime I get `big-bang: [new-name] clauses are not allowed within big-bang`.

I tried various variants of `define-syntax` but I could not make it work so far (that said, I'm a complete racket newbie).

Something like this works (well, `ladja` is not defined):

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/universe 2htdp/image)

(big-bang 0
            (on-tick (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))
            (to-draw (lambda (x) (place-image ladja 150 x (prazni-prostor 300 300))))
            (stop-when (lambda (x) (= x 300))))
```

But this doesn't (triggers the error):

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/universe 2htdp/image)

(define new-name on-tick)

(big-bang 0
            (new-name (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))
            (to-draw (lambda (x) (place-image ladja 150 x (prazni-prostor 300 300))))
            (stop-when (lambda (x) (= x 300))))
```

I see that `big-bang` [is a macro](https://github.com/racket/htdp/blob/master/htdp-lib/2htdp/universe.rkt#L261), so that explains the issue: I guess I would have to be able to force my macro to be evaluated first, somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're writing a module that you would require into your program, then you can use [`provide`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._provide%29%29) with [`rename-out`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._rename-out%29%29) to provide an alias:

In big-bang-with-new-name.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/universe 2htdp/image)

(provide big-bang
         to-draw
         stop-when
         empty-scene
         (rename-out [on-tick new-name]))
```

Using it in another file:

```
#lang racket

(require "big-bang-with-new-name.rkt")

(big-bang 0
          [new-name (lambda (x) (+ x 1))]
          [to-draw (lambda (x) (empty-scene 200 200))]
          [stop-when (lambda (x) (= x 300))])
```

Many macros use [`free-identifier=?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxcmp.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._free-identifier~3d~3f%29%29) to recognize keywords like this. [Rename transformers](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-rename-transformer%29%29) cooperate with `free-identifier=?` to create exact aliases. This means you can also define `new-name` as a rename transformer in the main file like this:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/universe 2htdp/image)

(define-syntax new-name (make-rename-transformer #'on-tick))

(big-bang 0
          [new-name (lambda (x) (+ x 1))]
          [to-draw (lambda (x) (empty-scene 200 200))]
          [stop-when (lambda (x) (= x 300))])
```